# Make a string Palindrome in C

Tags: c, palindrome, c-strings

James found a love letter his friend Harry has written for his girlfriend. James is a prankster, so he decides to meddle with the letter. He changes all the words in the letter into palindromes.

To do this, he follows 2 rules:

(a) He can reduce the value of a letter, e.g. he can change 'd' to 'c', but he cannot change 'c' to 'd'. 
(b) In order to form a palindrome, if he has to repeatedly reduce the value of a letter, he can do it until the letter becomes 'a'. Once a letter has been changed to 'a', it can no longer be changed.

Each reduction in the value of any letter is counted as a single operation. Find the minimum number of operations required to convert a given string into a palindrome.

Input Format 
The first line contains an integer T, i.e., the number of test cases. 
The next T lines will contain a string each. The strings do not contain any spaces.

Output Format 
A single line containing the number of minimum operations corresponding to each test case.

Constraints 
1 ≤ T ≤ 10
1 ≤ length of string ≤ 104 
All characters are lower case English letters.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */ 
    int count;
    int result;
    int i,j;

    scanf("%d",&count);

    for (i = 0 ; i < count ; i++){

        result = 0;

        char * string;
        scanf("%ms",&string);

        int k = (int)strlen(string);

        printf("Length: %d\n",k);

        int l = k/2;

        printf("L is: %d\n",l);

        for ( j = 0 ; j < l ; j++){

            printf("first char is is: %c\n",string[j]);
            printf("Second char is is: %c\n",string[k-j-1]);
            printf("Current loop count: %d\n",j);

            if ( string[j] != string [k-j] ){

                int g = (int)(string[j] - string[k-j-1]);
                if ( g > 0){
                    result += g;
                }
                else{
                    result -= g;
                }

            }
            else;

        }

        printf("%d\n",result);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Sample Input #00

```
4
abc
abcba
abcd
cba
```

Sample Output #00

```
2
0
4
2
```

Explanation

For the first test case, abc -> abb -> aba.
For the second test case, abcba is already palindromic string.
For the third test case, abcd -> abcc -> abcb -> abca = abca -> abba.
For the fourth test case, cba -> bba -> aba.

The above stated code is working for the given sample input, but it is not the correct one according to hacckerrank. Can someone point out the error please?

Comment: You never initialized the variable `string`.

Comment: @Barmar `scanf("%ms",&string);`. however, if `scanf()` fails, its another story.

Comment: That doesn't allocate space for the string. `string` is pointing to some random address in memory.

Comment: @SouravGhosh , scanf() is working for the given inputs.

Comment: 'string' is already a pointer, (and uninitialized, as @Barmar said).

Comment: Ahh, `%ms` is new to me, it's a POSIX extension that allocates the string space.

Comment: If you supply the address of the poninter, (&string), the scanf will spray the input data over the stack.

Comment: @Barmar - Oh!  New to me too; explains the '&string'.

Comment: @MartinJames well, I can't say its standard `C`, but its a POSIX extension, AFAIK.

Comment: string is a bad name, all identifiers that start with 'st' are reserved

Comment: I guess it's an acronym for 'malloced string'.  Not sure I like the idea.  Too easy to forget to free it.  Oh look - the OP did not free it!

Comment: hmm hackerrank says it runs ubuntu so %ms is allowable https://www.hackerrank.com/environment

Comment: `if ( string[j] != string [k-j] ){` is wrong. The second term in the condition should be `string[k-j-1]`. Also, you can simply skip the comparison. If `string[j]` equals `string[k-j-1]` then the difference will be zero. A simple loop body like `result += abs(string[j] - string[k-j-1])` should suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is here:

```
if ( string[j] != string [k-j] ){
```

The second character should be `string[k-j-1]`. For instance, when `j = 0`, you should compare with `string[k-1]` to compare the first and last characters of the string.

Also, you have a memory leak. At the bottom of the outer loop you should do:

```
free(string);
```

Comment: damn it! I knew I would make a mistake like this.. I was stuck here,thanks for the help.